# jQuery works locally, but not live

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, local

I've uploaded my first proper home page, which employs a few jQuery plug-ins.  These all work fine locally, but with all the relevant plugin files referenced and uploaded properly, it doesn't work when hosted on my server.

http://www.darrenbarklie.com

I've read other answers on SE, but I've still no idea why this is happening and really would appreciate any help afforded.  I've minimal experience with server-side admin, is there something I should be changing with the permissions?  I've spent loads of time on this and it's very frustrating to be stuck at the last hurdle.  jQuery doesn't appear to function if I host the file locally or link to googleapis.

Sincere thanks in advance.

(Please note that this is a work in progress, so there may be some cross-browser discrepancies - coded and test in FF only, thus far.)

Comment: Open up your chrome console and take a look at how many errors you are getting there... Looks like it's unable to load some key files..

Comment: What lix said. Look at your error console (or Firebug in Firefox) and start there.

Comment: 404 errors on most of your jQuery related resources.

Comment: I've nil experience with AJAX thus far; I'm only experienced with HTML, CSS, jQuery.  Can you point me in the right direction to learn about AJAX calls?

Comment: Appears your body onload function is commented out. Poshytip and hoverIntent js files don't look to be there.

Comment: look at path being generated for requests in console... then fix in code

Comment: It looks like the embedded spotify iframe is making an ajax call from within its self. If you take a look at the raw iframe, [https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:track:2bmcwHGuZW4E1051Dgd2HJ](https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:track:2bmcwHGuZW4E1051Dgd2HJ) you'll notice in the console the same error. Check your spotify url, something's wrong.

Comment: a little side note from someone in the tech recruiting industry... i took a look at your content on your site, and i can tell you up front that any company that knows anything about web development will see this line, "While I don't aspire to write my own solutions, I am comfortable implementing and amending existing code. Why do the work when it's already out there for free?" and will be immediately turned off. I'd suggest both changing your content and your attitude if you truly aspire to be a web developer (and learn how to include script files).

Comment: Thanks to everyone - seems like I've a long way to go yet!  :)

Comment: As Crockford says, never link to a server you don't have control of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You expose the structure of your `/js/` directory [**here**](http://www.darrenbarklie.com/js/)

You'll notice you reference hoverintent and poshytip wrong.

`poshytip.js` should be `poshytip.min.js` and `hoverIntent.js` should be `hoverintent.js`

Not to mention the issue with the iframe callback not working correctly....